# How do I console log the value of initialized useState in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Initializing values**

```js
const initialValues = {
  bag: 32,
  donor: "",
};
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
console.log(values.bag)
```

I don't know more about hooks but when I console.log the value is showing infinite looping value. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: learn to handle Component lifecycle, log this in `useEffect` hook for functional components and `componentDidMount`  for class base components.

Comment: @bakar_dev and `componentDidUpdate` for class-based components.

Comment: Have you tried - useEffect (()=>{console.log(values.bag)}) ?? in place of simple console.log ..!!

Comment: If your component is infinitely looping that means one of two things is occurring: (1) **THIS** component is updating its own state unguarded (i.e. no conditional test), or (2) something of the same type is occurring to **THIS** component's parent and thus the child is rerendered.

Comment: @Subhadeep not before I use useEffect I wanted to see if i can log my state value

Comment: @bakar_dev ok bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the functional components, you could set your state or put console.log into the useEffect() hook. Also, you could call your own function in this functional component to do the same. I am writing out both the scenarios in the below code snippet.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
export default function IntroToReact(){
const initialValues = {bag: 32,donor:""};


 const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

//Effect is called once during init
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(values.bag);
},[]);

//Effect is called everytime the values change
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(values.bag);
},[values]);

// Display the values
function onChangeValues(){
console.log(values.bag)
}

return (
<div>
{onChangeValues()}
</div>
);
}`
```

For further understanding, this concept you could refer to the official website of the react:- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

I hope it will help you.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hooks does not work inside classes. It works with function based component. It should always be used at the top level of the React Function.**

*I have run your code it's working fine. But you need to keep in mind some points using hooks first what syntax and approach you are following. Like your code needed to run in function-based component. I am adding a small snippet which is running fine.*

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
  function Home(){
     const initialValues = {
     bag: 90,
     donor: "",
    };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  console.log(values.bag)
  return(
   <div>
     <h1>Welcome To Home</h1>
   </div>
  );}export default Home;
```

*Set the indentation properly and call this component into your main component(if it is App.js or App.jsx and index.js or index.jsx)*

*Follow this official documentation of react.js. I am showing something in this documentation which will help you to know more about hooks.*

[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: When I move that code to `App.js` which is functional component it working but when I move it back to another functional component which has useEffect it loops. Now I got the problem. Thank you bro